# Programmatically change color of flowchart.js node

Tags: javascript, flowchart

I'm using [flowchart.js](https://flowchart.js.org/) and I want to change the color of a node via 
JavaScript on an event.

I can access the fill property of a node by entering:

```
diagram.diagram.symbols[0].symbol.attrs.fill
```

but setting a new value does not update the flowchart on the page. Eg,

```
diagram.diagram.symbols[0].symbol.attrs.fill = red
```

Is there a way to propagate an update to the diagram object? Or another approach for programmatically modifying a property?

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know you can't change background of specific node.
You can change the class of the node and redraw the graph. You can see and example [here](https://flowchart.js.org/)

In the second section you can see that they give each node a class like: `op1=>operation: My Operation|past`.

And you can define the class like this

```
'flowstate' : {'past' : { 'fill' : '#CCCCCC', 'font-size' : 12},}
```